# Ubuntu GNOME. GDM doesn't work after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: boot, nvidia, 16.10, gdm

Installed Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 yesterday, but after installing nvidia driver from software & updates the system wouldn't boot. I get the screen saying (numbers are slightly different):

```
dev/sda1: clean, 291272/4292608 files, 480345/18174432 blocks
```

Did some googling, found a few people solving similar issue by switching to lightdm. That worked (I was able to boot), but I was getting a ton of artifacts before and after the login screen, so I've tried to get the GDM to work.

Removed nvidia*, reinstalled it, re-downloaded gdm and ran:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
sudo service lightdm stop
```

after which the desktop turned off, but I was able to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and

```
sudo service gdm start
```

Now that actually worked yesterday, I did reboot a few times and got the login screen every time. However, it's not working today for some reason.

How do I make GDM work with nvidia drivers?

I am very new to Linux, in fact that is the first time I'm installing it.